# Move caret position after focus() for ContentEditable <DIV>

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I am trying to create a very basic rich-text editor in JavaScript but I'm having an issue with selections. So basically, since it's a contentEditable <div>, any time the user pastes in pre-formatted text from a webpage, the formatting doesn't get stripped off.

An easy to break hack is to give focus to a <textarea> upon Ctrl + V being pressed, so the text gets pasted in there, then onkeyup, give focus back to the <div>, copy the contents over and delete whatever went in to the <textarea>.

So that's easy, but when I give focus back to the contentEditable &;t;div>, the caret position is at the beginning and not immediately after the paste. I don't know enough about selections and whatnot to figure it out, so I'd appreciate some help. Here's my code:

```
// Helpers to keep track of the length of the thing we paste, the cursor position
// and a temporary random number so we can mark the position.
editor_stuff = 
{
    cursor_position: 0,
    paste_length: 0,
    temp_rand: 0,
}

// On key up (for the textarea).
document.getElementById("backup_editor").onkeyup = function() 
{ 
    var main_editor     =  document.getElementById("question_editor");
    var backup_editor   =  document.getElementById("backup_editor");
    var marker_position = main_editor.innerHTML.search(editor_stuff.temp_rand);

    // Replace the "marker" with the .value of the <textarea>
    main_editor.innerHTML = main_editor.innerHTML.replace(editor_stuff.temp_rand, backup_editor.value);

    backup_editor.value = "";

    main_editor.focus();
}

// On key down (for the contentEditable DIV).
document.getElementById("question_editor").onkeydown = function(event)
{
    key = event;

    // Grab control + V end handle paste so "plain text" is pasted and
    // not formatted text. This is easy to break with Edit -> Paste or
    // Right click -> Paste.

    if
    (
        (key.keyCode == 86 || key.charCode == 86) &&                   // "V".
        (key.keyCode == 17 || key.charCode == 17 || key.ctrlKey)       // "Ctrl"
    )
    {
        // Create a random number marker at the place where we paste.
        editor_stuff.temp_rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999));

        document.getElementById("question_editor").textContent +=  editor_stuff.temp_rand;
        document.getElementById("backup_editor").focus();
    }
}
```

So my thinking is to store the cursor position (integer) in my helper array (`editor_stuff.cursor_position`).

N.B. I've been looking at other answers on SO all day and can't get any of them to work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that inserts text at the caret position:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/Yuft3/2/

Code:

```
function pasteTextAtCaret(text) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);

            // Preserve the selection
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.setStartAfter(textNode);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tim. I was hoping it would be you that responded after seeing all your answers on the other selection related questions. I'm actually going to stop attempting to control the users input via JavaScript since its so easy to break the available solutions. No clue why they don't allow us to handle the text on-paste or allow a "force as plain text" function. I think PHP is a better way of handling the text. I have still used your code, though, because it's an excellent example of how to include tabs in the editor, which is something I was going to be looking in to very shortly anyway. Thanks!